# Java newbie, I can't select Java type of project

Tags: java

I want to use JUST Java category project, but NetBeans keeps showing me Java with Maven or Java with Gradle or Java with Ant.

Where do I find the pure Java category?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) is a build tool. After finishing the project, you can use Ant to build it. If you don't want to use it, it won't hinder you or affect your project in any way. It may add some folders in the project, but you can ignore them.